# Power Connectors for higher frequencies

Tags: connector, resonant-converter

I am currently involved in developing a resonant-converter for research purposes. One idea was to have two separate boards for each side of the involved transformer, while the heavy transformer could be independently fixed to the case. Connecting those parts could mean using connectors/plugs or soldering the wiring directly on the PCBs.

What I am unsure off:
To my knowledge connectors behave differently at higher frequencies, usually showing increased impedance. Obviously this would impact efficiency. So far I only know HF connectors for communication/RF or similar which address this. Would we need special connectors for this application?

The resonance frequency will be some hundreds of kHz and the working frequency will max out below 500 kHz. The desired signal formed by the resonance circuit is sinusoidal. The wiring would see about 400 V, 16 A (rms).

Comment: I would say 500 kHz is low-frequency enough to not need any special considerations for transmission-line effects.

Comment: @Felthry : I agree that this is not as fast as the HF that can be found in signal transmission. However I didn't find any base on which I could check which losses or impedance to expect. Most power connectors are tested and rated at DC or usual utility AC frequencies.

Comment: I would say that the loss should be no more significant than the loss in the rest of the cable, as long as your connectors give good contact. Basically, you can probably ignore the loss. If you're concerned about it, just measure it.